# Email notification from BizTalk for failed messages & error from event viewer

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p2aRN.png)Please let me know how to get email notification whenever an message fails in BizTalk and also whenever there is error in event viewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this depends on your solution. Within the solution I have developed, I have identified most points of failure on message routing, due to mistransformations, missing fields etc. These are then routed to an Orchestration which specifically only sends SMTP emails to set addresses. This works fairly well for the requirements of my company. - you can find plenty of SMTP Orchestration examples with a quick google.. I started [here](http://sharepointjack.com/2013/powershell-to-send-an-email-when-something-happens-in-the-event-log/)

In tandem with this - for the unknowns, I have also set up a powershell script to email out the last message of the Windows Log Event Viewer. I have created a custom viewer using the BizTalk Administrative console..

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[Provider[@Name='BizTalk DW Reporting' or @Name='BizTalk Server' or @Name='BizTalk Server Deployment' or @Name='BizTalk Server EDI' or @Name='ENTSSO' or @Name='XLANG/s'] and (Level=1  or Level=2)]]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

and then exported that out into a Windows Task Schedule, that triggers a powershell script whenever it detects that there is a new entry that lands in the custom viewer.

I have followed the rough principles provided [here](http://sharepointjack.com/2013/powershell-to-send-an-email-when-something-happens-in-the-event-log/) for the powershell script.

Hope this points you in the right direction for what you need. There are probably better solutions, but this works fairly well.

This is the powershell script I am using

```
$event = get-eventlog -LogName Application -Source "XLANG/s","BizTalk Server","BizTalk DW Reporting","BizTalk Server Deployment","BizTalk Server EDI","ENTSSO" -EntryType "Error" -newest 1
#get-help get-eventlog will show there are a handful of other options available for selecting the log entry you want.
$eventtime = $event.TimeGenerated


#ignore any messagebox errors
if (($event.EntryType -eq "Error"  -and $event.EventID -inotin 6998, 10514))
{
    $Source = $event.Source
    $PCName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
    $EmailBody = "$Source Error captured at " + $event.TimeGenerated + " in windows error log on BizTalk-UAT server: `n`n" + $event.Message
    $EmailFrom = "????-BizTalk-UAT@???.com"
    $EmailTo = @('????-BizTalk-UAT@???.com') 
    $EmailSubject = "BizTalk-UAT Server - Windows Log - " + $event.EntryType
    $SMTPServer = "mail.????.com"
    Write-host "Sending Email" $EmailFrom "To" $EmailTo
    Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSubject -body $EmailBody -SmtpServer $SMTPServer

}
else
{
    write-host "No error found"
    write-host "Here is the log entry that was inspected:"
$event
}
```

Comment: Thank you Arix . I will use powershell now & later use Orchestration .

Comment: Please let me know how I should configure the step 4 & 5 from above link . Attached the configuration I have but its not working . The script are at C:\BiztalkServerAlert\BiztalkAlerts.ps1

Comment: For step 4 In the program script box, type powershell.exe, without the directory. For step 5 put the directory of the script and the script name in the add arguments box - "D:\myscript.ps1" with the double quotes. I'm not at my machine right now but that's how I remember it.

Comment: I have attached the code I have but I not getting any result when I execute the script .Please verify .

Comment: I have added the code I have in use on the UAT server within my original answer. IF this works, please mark my answer up.

Comment: I got the below error while executing the code withn my company SMTP server & gmail . Please let me know if I need to change settings .---PS C:\Users\Svc3plBiztk> C:\BiztalkServerAlert\BiztalkAlerts.ps1
Sending Email notify-noreply@wirelessadvocates.com To BTSUAT@wirelessadvocates.com
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.1 Client was not authenticated
At C:\BiztalkServerAlert\BiztalkAlerts.ps1:17 char:5
+     Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSub ...
-------------------

Comment: PS C:\Users\Svc3plBiztk> C:\BiztalkServerAlert\BiztalkAlerts.ps1
Sending Email Selvaraj.Munusamy11@gmail.com To BTSUAT@wirelessadvocates.com
Send-MailMessage : The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Must issue a STARTTLS command first. k63sm16763164pfc.76 - gsmtp
At C:\BiztalkServerAlert\BiztalkAlerts.ps1:17 char:5
+     Send-MailMessage -From $EmailFrom -To $EmailTo -Subject $EmailSub ...

Comment: It looks to me as though you have a permissions issue, do you need a username and password for your connection perhaps? I never encountered this issue so I have no idea which direction to point you in, it may be worth taking the error message and looking through stack for solutions to the issue. Sorry I couldn't be more help

Comment: Thank you Arix . I was able to establish connection & send email .But please let me know how I can prevent duplicate email notification for same error .Is there an way to clear the custom event viwer?

Comment: This method generally works by returning the newest error when run and is triggered by the XML exported from the event viewer. What I have done over time is slowly remove errors that I don't want emailed, such as message box errors etc.. but I never wanted to remove duplicates. If you want to stop duplicates, you probably want to do a check on the record before the one that is being pulled for the email and check whether the error eventid is the same. Again, I have not had to do this so I have no code to hand. I don't speak powershell fluent enough to provide an example sorry

Comment: Okay . Thank you Arix .

Answer (score 0):

The 'correct' way to do this is with a monitoring tool for Windows and other platforms.

First, as your network or server team if they have a tool such as SCOM or Splunk which they should be using to monitor the servers anyway.  Then, you can configure any rule you/they want, including email.

In your BizTalk Apps, just be sure to create Windows Events (Event Viewer) in you exception handling code.

Comment: Ok . Please let me know if we have any other option with Biztalk itself .

Comment: @SelvarajMunusamy That is the way with BizTalk.  All these capabilities are supported by other parts of the stack so there's no need to duplicate them in BizTalk.  That just add complexity.

Comment: Ok . I am also waiting for response from network team .